# Arduino Ethernet Client crashes after obtaining values from string

Tags: arduino-mega, ethernet

My Ethernet server keeps crashing after pulling the RGB values from the string. It remains connected if I'm just toggling a pin, but whenever the string has the rgb values in it, the RGB values are pulled, the LED changes but then the server crashes and won't take any more requests. Do I need to restart the server after it plucks the RGB values for another read? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks, James :)

Example HTTP request that causes the crash: /?LED=B233+G011+R133&t=T HTTP/1.1

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <Ethernet.h>
    #include <string.h>

    byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; 
    byte ip[] = {192, 168, 0, 102 }; 
    byte gateway[] = {192, 168, 0, 1 }; 
    byte subnet[] = {255, 255, 255, 0 }; 
    EthernetServer server(84);
    ; 

    char* redstring={0};
    String blue1;
    String green1;
    String red1;
    String testString = "0123456789";


    int blue;
    int green;
    int red;
    int been=0;
    int b=0;
    int g=0;
    int r=0;
    //////////////////////

    void setup(){

    pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);

    //start Ethernet
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
    server.begin();

    //enable serial data print 
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    Serial.println("SERVER RUNNING HTTP / GET"); 
    }

    void loop(){
     ////////////////////////////////////////
     EthernetClient client = server.available();
if (client) {
while (client.connected()) {
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();

    //read char by char HTTP request
    if (sizeof(redstring) < 100) {

      //store characters to string 
      redstring += c; 
      //Serial.print(c);
    } 

    //if HTTP request has ended
    if (c == '\n') {

      ///////////////////////////////////////////

      Serial.println(redstring);



      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
      client.println();
      client.println("<HTML>");
      client.println("<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"data:image/x-icon;,\" type=\"image/x-icon\">"); 
      client.println("<HEAD>");
      client.println("<TITLE>Arduino GET</TITLE>");
      client.println("</HEAD>");
      client.println("<BODY>");

      client.println("<H1>HTML GET</H1>");
      //change ip back if not local
      client.println("<FORM ACTION=\"http://192.168.0.102:84\" method=get >");

      client.println("JQUERY: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=\"LED\" VALUE=\"\" SIZE=\"25\" MAXLENGTH=\"50\"><BR>");

      client.println("<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME=\"t\" VALUE=\"T\">");

      client.println("</FORM>");

      client.println("<BR>");

      client.println("</BODY>");
      client.println("</HTML>");

      delay(1);
      //stopping client
      client.stop();
      /////////////////////
      //readString = Character.toUpperCase(readString); 
      for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(redstring); i++) {
        if (strchr(redstring, 'B') && && redstring[i+1] > -1) {
          blue=redstring[i+1, i+4];
          analogWrite(11, blue); 
          delay(1000);
                      }

        if (strchr(redstring, 'G') && redstring[i+1] > -1) {
          green=redstring[i+1, i+4];
          analogWrite(9, green); 
          delay(1000);
                      }


        if (strchr(redstring, 'R')&& redstring[i+1] > -1) {
          red=redstring[i+1, i+4];
          analogWrite(7, red); 
          delay(1000);
                      }



      }






      //clearing string for next read
           redstring="";
          (redstring, "0", sizeof(redstring));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you compile this program with Arduino IDE, what does it tell you about the amount of memeory used? It looks your program uses **a lot** of SRAM and it may quickly happen that memory gets exhausted during runtime.

Comment: It complies fine and just says the typical: Binary sketch size: 16,688 bytes (of a 258,048 byte maximum). It only appears to crash when I use RED, blue and green are fine and I can execute it as many times as I want, as soon as it finds red it crashes.

Comment: It seems you have an Arduino Mega, right? When I was talking about memory, I was referring to SRAM (data), not Flash (code). This is where you can have an issue (8KB limit on Mega). But more improtant: avoid using `String` as it is a source of this kind of crashes, due to memory heap fragmentation.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the Mega.
How would I check the SRAM usage?
Hmm, what would you suggest using except string? Or would you suggest doing this another way?

Comment: Arduino IDE shows the amount od SRAM used for data after compilation. I got it on 1.5.7; I'm not sure this also works on 1.0.5 though.

Comment: I have tried compiling your program on my own Aduino IDE 1.5.7 for Arduino MEGA; it claims 946 bytes are used for SRAM (11% of 8K available on Mega). Normally that should be enough, but I think those `String` variable definitely make the difference (they use dynamic memory allocation / deallocation, which can quickly lead to heap fragmentation). In general it is preferrable to use C string style, i.e. `char*` or `char xxx[SIZE]`, and stick with standard C string functions like `strchr`, `strstr` or `strtok` for what you do.

Comment: Ah, okay! Thank you so much for your help! I'll give that a go! :)

Comment: It's still crashing even when using char instead of string. As soon as it reads and sets the 3 colours, it crashes. This also happens if it reads and sets two numbers, the first is fine and the second causes it to crash.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the following info: example HTTP request that makes the program crash. Also you say chaging `String` to C string style still has issues, could you please add the updated program with C-strings to your post? I ask because using C string style is not as straightforward as `String` and if not done properly can lead to crashes (but here, those are due to programming errors, not memory exhaustion).

Comment: Changing `String` into `char*` won't do the trick, there is much more rework required than that; sicne we start to have many comments I think I will post that as an answer.

Comment: As a first order approximation, `redstring += c;` does not do anything you want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `String`, which uses dynamic allocation/deallocation on the heap is not advised in embedded platforms, as this can quickly lead to heap fragmentation, eventually leading to memory exhaustion, heap/stack collision...

First off, you should try to replace all `String` usage, everywhere in your program, with C-tyle strings, i.e. `char*` or `char xxx[...]` along with dedicated C functions to deal with them: `strchr`, `strstr`, `strcpy`, `strcat`, `strtok`, `atoi`...

Second, you can avoid using global variables and use the stack for many of them.

```
void loop() {
    ...
    if (client) {
        char readString[101];
        const int READ_STRING_SIZE = sizeof(readString) - 1;
        int readIndex = 0;
        while (client.connected()) {
            if (client.available()) {
                char c = client.read();
                if (readIndex < READ_STRING_SIZE) {
                    readString[readIndex++] = c;
                }

                if (c == '\n') {
                    // Terminate the read string
                    readString[readIndex] = 0;
                    Serial.println(readString);

                    // Prepare for next reeading
                    readIndex = 0;

                    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                    ...
                    client.stop();

                    // convert readString to all uppercase
                    for (i = 0; i < strlen(readString); i++)
                        readString[i] = toupper(readString[i]);

                    bool b = false;
                    bool r = false;
                    bool g = false;
                    int blue, red, green;

                    // Look for 'B' value
                    char* bb = strchr(readString, 'B');
                    if (bb != 0 && isdigit(bb[1]) {
                        blue = atoi(&bb[1]);
                        analogWrite(11, blue);
                        delay(500);
                        b = true;
                    }
                    // Same for 'G' and 'R' value
                    ...
                    if (b && r && g) {
                        Serial.print("CHANGING RED TO: ");
                        Serial.println(red);
                        Serial.print("CHANGING GREEN TO: ");
                        Serial.println(green);
                        Serial.print("CHANGING BLUE TO: ");
                        Serial.println(blue);
                    }
                }

                if (strstr(readString, "PIN6") != 0) {
                    digitalWrite(6, !digitalRead(6));
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this sample code, we have completely removed dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!
How would I clear the C-String? It keeps looping and doesn't toggle the pin, rather just makes it flash.

Comment: See my edit: I had forgotten to reset `readIndex` once a whole string has been read. Now it should work properly.

Comment: ah okay, thanks! 
Another issue I found is that the code breaks the string when it hit's a 'B' but doesn't get the next 3 numbers, but instead copys the http request from the string and tries to make it an int and set the LED, but it just returns a 0. How would I replicate the `blue = redstring[i + 1, i + 4];` (to get the 3 numbers after the 'B' like mine?)

Comment: Oops, my mistake, see my edit: `atoi(&bb[1])` instead of `atoi(bb)`.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you!
The same issue is occuring, as soon as I pass three colours, the server disconnects and won't take any more requests. Could this be a problem with the way I have set my server up?

Comment: I checked my code and realised it wasn't exactly like your example, with the help of your example I can now do multiple colours but as soon as I switch on PIN6 after setting the RGB LED, it crashes again.

Comment: Before we go further, could you clarify the "it crashes" statement. It would be useful to know if the MCU really crashes (eg memory problems) or if the program is in an infinite loop, in the latter case it would be useful to know exactly where this loop is.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the issue is, the webpage will become unresponsive and the lights indicating the Ethernet connection turn off. From what I have tested from the serial monitor, it appears the program is not looping but unexpectedly quitting. Furthermore, each statement (PIN6 & RGB) can be repeated infinitely as long as I don't mix the two statements and only execute one or the other.

Comment: I would suggest to ask another question with the latest code you have, and detail the observed problem, otherwise it will become very difficult to follow this Q&A thread. You can refer to this question from the new one just so that people can get some context about previous discussions if they want to.